# components of an SPSS project

Tags: file, project, spss

I have given some data in an excel sheet to a 3rd party for SPSS data processing. After completion of the processing, what are the files that I should get back from them.

I have received one file with a ".sav" extension. I presume this file contains the imported data (from my excel file).

I have received  documents (.rtf - rich text format) with the chart and graphs only. Is there something else I need to get so that I can use the files later on for further analysis.

Thanks in advance
V Karthick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the ".sav" extension is the data file.  You should also request the syntax file(s), ".sps" extension. The syntax file is a record of all data transformations which have been performed and allows you to review their work.  The syntax file can be opened with notepad or any text editor.

Arthur